# javascript onClick call style - some working and some not

Tags: javascript, html

It should be something very basic but I could not explain the following result.
I know similar questions have been asked before, but none of those really helped me explain this.
Can anyone please help me understand why only the last onClick (CLICK HERE3) shows the alert and not the other two.

In my situation, I really need to call the test() function from some other function and not directly. Do I really need to use bind here?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function test()
{
alert('hi');
}
</script>

<style>
i {
cursor:pointer;
text-decoration:underline;
}

</style>

</head>
<body>
     <div>
    <i id="1" onClick="return function(){test();}">CLICK HERE1</i>
    <br/>
    <i id="2" onClick="function(){test();}">CLICK HERE2</i>
    <br/>
    <i id="3" onClick="return test();">CLICK HERE3</i>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Appreciate your help.

Comment: First returns a function that is never called. Second defines a function that is never called. Third calls `test()`. *"I really need to call the test() function from some other function and not directly."* - Why? What does the other function you are talking about do?

Comment: just Onclick="test()" is enough, the 1st and 2nd return a function onclick, only the 3rd one runs it.

Comment: if you want to call test from someother function then onclick="(function(){test();})()"

Comment: You have to call the functions.  Try these for the first two.  `onClick="return function(){test();}()"` and `onClick="function(){test();}()"`

Comment: RJM and karthick s explanation helped me understand the first two issues. But, how is that in the third case as well, I am just returning a function- right? so why did that work?

Comment: No... the third case you are running the `test` and then returning the return of the `test` function (when the event click happens of course)

Comment: so onClick="function{}{/**some code **/}" never actually calls the anonymous function? but onClick="return test()" calls the test() function. In that case, why onClick="return function(){test();}" would not work? I am just confused. Can you please point out any link where I can read about this ? Thanks much for your help.